# Problems with find_one_and_update using Pymongo/Flask with React application

Tags: reactjs, flask, pymongo, mongodb-atlas, http-status-code-400

I am working on the administrator part of a beginner's project I'm working on. I'm building in React.js with Pymongo/Flask connected to MongoDB Atlas for database storage. The page I'm working on allows the administrator to query the database to return all the users for a particular course they are taking or role they have (instructor or administrator). The returned data is mapped over to child components in React with a series of input fields using the defaultValue being populated by the props for the children (i.e. first name, last name, email, etc.). I'm saving new values to the child components' states and using JSON.stringify to make an axios.patch request. I'd like to be able to alter any user's information and submit it to the Mongo DB Atlas server, but am having some issues.

Here is what I think would be the necessary code from the front end:

```
  saveChanges(id, data) {
    var token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("token")
    const updata = JSON.stringify(data)
    axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/update-instructor/${id}`, JSON.stringify({updata}), { headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`}})
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("There was an error with the patch request to instructor", error)
    })
  }
```

On the backend, this is the route that axios is calling:

```
@app.route('/update-instructor/<id>', methods=['GET', 'PATCH'])
def update_one_instructor(id):
  id = ObjectId(id)
  id_call = {"_id" : id}

  updateObject = request.get_json(force=True)

  instructors.find_one_and_update(id_call, 
  { "$set" : { updateObject } },
  return_document = ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

The imports and setup of my flask/Pymongo:

```
import datetime
from distutils.log import error
import json

import pymongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from bson import json_util
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
from flask_jwt_extended import decode_token
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, Response, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from pymongo import ReturnDocument
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

CONNECTION_URL = *connection url*

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
cors = CORS(app)

app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = *secret key*
jwt = JWTManager(app)


try:
  client = pymongo.MongoClient(CONNECTION_URL, serverSelectionTimeoutMS = 10000)

except:
  print("Error - cannot connect to database")

Database = client.get_database(*database name*)

instructors = Database.instructors
```

I'm getting several issues. On the front end in Chrome, I am getting:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/update-instructor/*string of ObjectID*' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

as well as:

```
PATCH http://127.0.0.1:5000/update-instructor/*string of ObjectID* net::ERR_FAILED
```

On the backend I'm getting a 400 error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2022 17:17:43] "OPTIONS /update-instructor/*string of ObjectID* HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Might be unecessary information here; but I'm not sure what is relevant. Any ideas on how I can get this patch request to go through and update MongoDB Atlas and, subsequently, the state in my parent component?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It seems it was an error in my Pymongo/Flask setup.

```
@app.route('/update-user/<id>', methods=['GET', 'PATCH'])
def update_one_user(id):
  id = ObjectId(id)

  updateObject = request.get_json()
  jsonify(updateObject)

  result = users.find_one_and_update({"_id" : id}, 
  { "$set" : updateObject },
  return_document = ReturnDocument.AFTER)

  return "User Updated"
```

I also did some refactoring, so the route is slightly changed. Basically it seems that using fewer variables as well as well as removing the {} from updateObject did the trick. But I also refactored my front end code to

```
  saveChanges(id, data) {
    let config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
      }
    axios.patch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/update-user/${id}`, JSON.stringify(data), config)
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("There was an error with the patch request to instructor", error)
    })
  }
```

It now includes some extra headers for CORS, but was was pointed out to me, it was the http 400 that was causing the CORS issue.